# Ordered set with a smallest element with element having a successor and and predecessor, not similar to the natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm looking to give an ordered set that is not similar to $\mathbb N$ with a smallest element in which every element has a successor and a predecessor, which wouldn't apply to the least (that is the predecessor).

$\displaystyle \left\{\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n} : n=1,2,3,...\right\}$

In this set, the least would be infinitesimally small as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Is this logic correct?

Comment: This set doesn't contain a least element (assuming that your order is the natural order on rationals).

Comment: @Stefan: Yes it does: $-1$.

Comment: Yes, this is a fine example. Its order type can be described as $\Bbb N+\Bbb Z$: in effect you’ve added a copy of $\Bbb Z$ to a copy of $\Bbb Z$. It’s the simplest order type that does what you want.

Comment: The  idea will work, with careful specification of the successor, predecessor relation. I would instead  take a copy of the natural numbers and colour them red. Then take a copy of the **integers** and colour them blue. The order relation between two reds or two blues is the natural one. And every blue is greater than any red.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So this still work if it was n=2,3,4,...  or really any starting point of n, so then my comment about "the least would be infinitesimally small.." that part is wrong. That first element, with the smallest n, is establishing the least element.

Comment: @Brian Whoops. I totally got thrown off by the "the least would be infinitesimally small" comment. My bad.

Comment: @Learner: Yes, that’s right. I just noticed the bit about *infinitesimally small* and was about to add to my comment, but you’ve caught the error yourself now. You should look at **André**’s comment for a simpler way to describe such an order, and at **Stefan**’s answer for a nice technical solution.

Comment: @Stefan: And I didn’t notice it until after my first two comments, so I saw the correctness of the example but missed the error in the explanation! Fortunately, all seems to be straightened out now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such an order exists: Let $X = \{0\} \times \mathbb N_0 \cup \{1\} \times \mathbb Z$ and for $(a,b),(c,d) \in X$ let $(a,b) \prec (c,d)$ iff $a < c$ or $a = c$ and $b < d$ (where $<$ denotes the natural order on $\mathbb Z$ and we consider $\mathbb N_0$ as a subset of $\mathbb Z$).

$(X, \prec)$ looks like $\mathbb N_0$ with $\mathbb Z$ "put on top", i.e. the first few elements of $(X, \prec)$ are $(0,0) \prec (0,1) \prec \ldots \prec (0,n)$ which may be thought of as the natural numbers $0 < 1 < \ldots < n$ and then we have $(0,n) \prec (1,z)$ for every $n \in \mathbb N_0$ and every $z \in \mathbb Z$.

It's easy to check that every element of $X$ has a unique successor and (if the element is not $(0,0)$) a unique predecessor. Since $(X, \prec)$ contains an infinite decreasing sequence (namely $(1,0) \succ (1,-1) \succ (1,-2) \succ \ldots$) it is not similar to $(\mathbb N_0, < )$.

---

edit: Note that André came up with the same ordering in his comment: His "red" copy of natural numbers relates to those $(0,n)$ for $n \in \mathbb N_0$ and his "blue" copy of integers are represented as $(1,z)$ for $z \in \mathbb Z$. By definition $\prec$ restricted to either "red" or "blue" elements is just the usual order on the "red natural numbers" or "blue integers" and every "red natural" is below every "blue integer".